# How to perform present value analysis for given options?

Tags: math, economics

Standard University has just completed the design of a student record information system, and now has two choices for developing it:

1. D1: Total system development, requiring 20 programmers for one year.
2. D2: Incremental development, requiring 10 programmers for two
   years.

Each programmer begins with a salary of $2k per month, paid at the beginning of each month, and receives a 10% raise after one year. The interest rate is 0.85% per month, compounded monthly. Perform a present value analysis of options D1 and D2, and determine which is preferable on a present value basis.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not directly about programming.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
D1 = 40,000 x 0.9915^0 + 40,000 x 0.9915^1 + ... + 40,000 x 0.9915^11
   = 40,000 x (0.9915^0 + 0.9915^1 + ... + 0.9915^11)
   = 40,000 x (1 - 0.9915^12) / (1 - 0.9915)
   ~ 458,183.80
```

Option 2:

```
D2 =   20,000 x (0.9915^0 + 0.9915^1 + ... + 0.9915^11)    // 1st year at 1st year's pay
     + 22,000 x (0.9915^0 + 0.9915^1 + ... + 0.9915^23)    // both years at 2nd year's pay
     - 22,000 x (0.9915^0 + 0.9915^1 + ... + 0.9915^11)    // 1st year at 2nd year's pay

   =   20,000 x (1 - 0.9915^12) / (1 - 0.9915)
     + 22,000 x (1 - 0.9915^24) / (1 - 0.9915)
     - 22,000 x (1 - 0.9915^12) / (1 - 0.9915)

   ~   229,091.9020
     + 479,466.3354
     - 252,001.0922

   ~ 456,557.15
```

We multiply by 0.9915^k = (1 - 0.0085)^k to get the present value of the monthly pay to all developers at the beginning of month k. This applies the discount implied by the interest rate. We use the formula for partial sums of a geometric series to simplify 1 + r + r^2 + ... + r^k to (1 - r^(k+1)) / (1 - r). For D2, we calculate the 2nd year's pay's present value by first calculating the present value assuming the 2nd year's rate of pay for both years, then subtracting the portion of that which came from the first year (since we already accounted for it in the first year's rate of pay).